# C function error LNK2019 in main

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I am a Student and just started learning C.
I cant find the problem here what is the meaning of this error??

this is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>

int Digitquantity(int);
int Digitsorted(int);
int Simmetric3(int);
int Fibonaccinumber(int);

int main(void){
    int N, i; //N for Natural Number, i for number of digits in N
    printf("please enter a natural number:");
    scanf("%d", &N);
    i = Digitsquantity(N);
    if (Digitsorted(N) || Simmetric3(N) || Fibonaccinumber(N)){
    if (Simmetric3(N))
        printf("This is a Simmetric 3 Number\n");
    if (Digitsorted(N))
        printf("This Number is Digit Sorted\n");
    if (Fibonnacinumber(N))
        printf("This is a Fibonacci Number\n");
    }
    else printf("No attribute is satisfied.");
    getch();
    return(0);
}
int Digitquantity(int num){
    int i = 0;
    while (num != 0){
        num = num / 10;
        i++;
    }
    return(i);
}

int Digitsorted(int n) {
    int tens, units; // units for the number to the right of n, tens is the number after that.  
    units = n % 10;
    tens = (n % 100) / 10;
    if (tens >= units){
        n = n / 10;
        if (n >= 0 && n < 10){ return(1); }
        else { Digitsorted(n); }
    }
    else if (tens < units) return(0);
}

int Simetric3(int nu){
    return(1);
}

int Fibonaccinumber(int numb){
    return(1);
}
```

and this is the error i get:

```
Error   6   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _Digitsquantity referenced in function _main  D:\מלמ\homework\homework\q2.obj
Error   7   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _Fibonnacinumber referenced in function _main D:\מלמ\homework\homework\q2.obj
Error   5   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _Simmetric3 referenced in function _main  D:\מלמ\homework\homework\q2.obj
```

This is actually homework... And its not finished yet but I want to see if 2 of the functions I wrote are working by running it and I cant compile because I get these errors witch I don't understand.

can someone please point out whats wrong with the code?

Comment: All typos. Check your function prototypes and the actual function calls/definitions.

Comment: Wow im such an Idiot!!!!

Comment: -Yeah.. there's a reason that copy/paste is so popular:)

Comment: LOL its working!!! thank you Blue Moon!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're being inconsistent in your use of function names.  For example, you declare "Digitquantify()", but you call "Digit**s**quantify()".